# I am writing a event code in personal.xlsb to do spell check inside a cell

Tags: vba

Codes added in Class Module 'CAppEventHandler'

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Call CheckSpelling1   
End Sub
```

Codes added in "ThisWorkbook" Module of personal.xlsb

```
Option Explicit

Private OurEventHandler As CAppEventHandler


Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
     Set OurEventHandler = New CAppEventHandler
End Sub
```

Code for checking spelling in cell

```
Sub CheckSpelling1(r As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Dim ar() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

With Application.SpellingOptions
    .IgnoreCaps = True
    .IgnoreFileNames = True
    .IgnoreMixedDigits = True
End With
 
    For Each rng In r
        If Not rng.HasFormula And VarType(rng.Value) = vbString Then
            ar = Split(Replace(rng.Value, Chr(160), " "), " ")
            j = 1
            rng.Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
            For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
                If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=ar(i)) Then
                    rng.Characters(j, Len(ar(i))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
                j = j + 1 + Len(ar(i))
            Next i
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

I have checked many posts on how to handle events meant for all workbooks. But as I am a starter on VBA, cannot get it to work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try initializing the class in the `Open` event:

1.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set OurEventHandler = New CAppEventHandler
End Sub
```

Being a hidden workbook, the `Workbook_SheetChange` event will never be triggered.
Anyhow, if the `Personal.xlsb` is already open, you can/have to manually run the event, instead of closing and reopening it. The class **must be initialized** in order to be possible to use the created event.

Only after that the `SheetChange` event of all open workbooks will trigger the one defined in the class.

2. Then, the `CheckSpelling1` sub must be called using its (`Range`) argument:

```
Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    CheckSpelling1 Target
End Sub
```

Comment: @Surendra Mishra: Glad I could help!